# Rubocop only to check modified lines

Tags: ruby, git, rubocop

I would like to run rubocop on the terminal only for the lines that I have modified within a git versioned project. Currently, from googling, I see scripts which work on the entire modified file.

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/skanev/9d4bec97d5a6825eaaf6) but what I understand from the documentation is that it shows false positives and negatives.

Comment: ... I am sitting on a 2/3rds-finished Gem for doing this. I don't think there is an existing solution.

Comment: @meagar: look forward to it :)

Comment: I should mention, as far as hosted solutions, there is [Hound](https://houndci.com/).

Comment: I know about Hound. I want something local

Comment: It is over 7.5 years later, and I would like to know, is there any progress on this issue since the original post?

Comment: Never mind...I realized I should take a look at pronto to see how it has developed since it was mentioned here. I have been trying it out and it's amaaaaazing. Check out the readme at https://github.com/prontolabs/pronto. All I needed to do was `gem install pronto`, `gem install pronto-rubocop`, and then run `pronto run -c my-branch-to-compare-with`.

Answer (score 8):

Pronto is gem that can do that - install `pronto` and `pronto-rubocop`.

If you want you can use this gist https://gist.github.com/alkuzad/dd729aca36a810892772 that I've used a lot before I was using pronto (it's still handy because pronto is not so flexible about diff). You have to install showlinenum from  https://github.com/jay/showlinenum to ~/bin to get it work (or just modify the path in gist)

Answer (score 0):

As I can see there is no option to force Rubocop check some lines, it can only be scoped by files. But it's possible to filter Rubocop output to highlight only modified lines.

This will show Rubocop offences only for modified and unstaged files (in context of current Git repo):

```bash
rubocop $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d) | \
reviewdog -f=rubocop -diff="git diff" -fail-on-error -filter-mode="added"
```

It requires Reviewdog https://github.com/reviewdog/reviewdog#installation