# run rubocop only on affected lines

Tags: ruby, bash, git, rubocop

I recently joined a company, and we use RuboCop as the static code analysis tool.

I created a script to run RuboCop in the files I worked on. For the newly created files is fine, but when I modify an existing one sometimes triggers a lot of changes in lines that I dit not introduced.

this is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $HOME/Documents/repos/{projectName}
files=`git status --porcelain | awk '{ print $2 }'`
for f in $files;
do  
    rubocop -a $f
done
```

Is there any way I can modify this script to check only the lines that have changed?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this provide an answer to your question? [Rubocop only to check modified lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29329385/421705)

Comment: Note that there is also a very effective static analysis tool for Bash (and other shell) code.  It is [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: @HolgerJust not exactly but I managed to put pronto along with rubocop and it works nearly as I expect, I will leave this question open because still room for improvement. thanks

Comment: @pjh are you trying to say something about my bash skills? :joy:

Answer (score 0):

As I can see there is no way to run Rubocop on some lines, it can only be scoped by files. There is an option to filter Rubocop output to highlight only modified lines.

This will show Rubocop offences only for modified and unstaged files (in context of current Git repo):

```bash
rubocop $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d) | \
reviewdog -f=rubocop -diff="git diff" -fail-on-error -filter-mode="added"
```

It requires Reviewdog https://github.com/reviewdog/reviewdog#installation